# Configurar list-group com scrollspy bootstrap

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap, div

Boa noite !
   Estou com dificuldade com um dos layouts do meu projeto no qual eu tenho uma div dividida em 3 partes, aonde a parte direita superios conterá cards que selecionados trarão os dados em uma lista na parte inferior, estou construindo a interface ainda, e nos testes que estou fazendo quero que essa div se adeque ao temanho da tela do computador, e a lista possua uma barra de rolagem, do jeito que está o meu código abaixo a lista ultrapassa o tamanho da tela:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- page 2-->
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <!-- metas obrigatórios para o bootstrap para compatibilidades-->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- LINK OBRIGATÓRIOS PARA BOOTSTRAP, SWEETALERT2 E ANIMATE.CSS-->
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Add icon library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <title>Home Page</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid my-3 block_demarcacao0">

        <div class="row block_demarcacao">

            <div class="col-md-9 block_demarcacaol">
                <!--linha 1 dos cards -->
                <div class="row block_demarcacao">

                    <!--card 1-->
                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--aguardando">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Aguardando atendimento
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">5</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <!--card 2-->
                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--pausa">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Em Pausa
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">12</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <!--card 3-->
                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--feedback">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Aguardando Feedback
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-deaf"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">3</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>   
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--linha 2 dos cards-->
                <div class="row block_demarcacao">

                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--homologacao">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Em Homologação
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-bug"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">5</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--agendado">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Agendados
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">5</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!--FIM DOS CARDS -->

                <!--LISTA DE CHAMADOS -->
                <div class="row block_demarcacaolista">
                    <div class="container-fluid list-group" data-spy="scroll">

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 block_demarcacaol">
                <span>Aqui fica o SATI em atendimento</span>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!--Componentes opcionais mas importantissimos sempre seguindo essa ordem jquery, popper, bootstrap-->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scriptsSweet.js"></script>

</body>
```

CSS

```
.block--footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
}

.block--navbar{
background-color: #030040;
}

.block__logo{
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
}

.block__input{
margin-top: 15px;
}

.block__btnprimary{
margin-top: 15px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 20px;
background: white;
color: blue;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: blue;
}

.block--navbar__logo{
width: 100px;
height: 35px;
}

.block--navbar__link {
font-size: 18px;
color: rgba($black, .5);
}

.block--navbar__icon {
font-size: 60px;
color: rgba($black, .5);
}

.block--navbar__link:hover {
font-size: 21px;
color: rgba($primaryDark, .8);
.block--navbar__icon{ color: rgba(blue, 0.8)};
}

.block--navbar__profile{
font-size: 23px;
color: rgba($black, .5);
}

.block__card{
width: 180px;
height: 100px;
text-align: end;
min-width: 50px;
font-size: 11px;
color: white;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border: 0ch;
}

.block__card:hover{
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
}

.block__card--pausa{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(138, 138, 4);
}

.block__card--agendado{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(228, 61, 32);
}

.block__card--aguardando{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: blue;
}

.block__card--feedback{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(11, 152, 207);
}

.block__card--homologacao{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(40, 5, 73);
}

.block__card--dados{
 font-size: 22px;
text-align: start;
}

.block_demarcacao{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #030040;
}

.block_demarcacaol{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #BF622D;
}

.block_demarcacao0{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: brown;
}

.block_demarcacaolista{
height: 350px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: brown;
}
```

Da forma como está ele exibe as 3 partes mais ou menos como eu preciso, porém não estou conseguindo limitar o tamanho delas, no caso, da div que conterá a lista de chamados por categoria.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu fixei o tamanho da div inferior apenas para tentar forçar o scrollspy, porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Só olhando a imagem e com o código que postou fica difícil de verificar e reproduzir a página para tentar simular o problema e encontrar uma solução.

Comment: Desculpe, eu havia postado o código da pagina errada, verifique se melhorou por favor

Comment: Vc quer ajustar esta div "block_demarcacaolista" para que não ultrapasse a tela e ganhe um scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que com CSS você não conseguirá fazer isso, porque as dimensões das outras `divs` podem variar e o CSS não saberá lidar com isso.

Com jQuery você pode fazer isso com facilidade. Primeiro ajuste no CSS a classe da `div`, colocando `overflow: auto` e setando `height: 0;`:

```
.block_demarcacaolista{
   height: 0;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-color: brown;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Em seguida adicione o script abaixo na página:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(window).on("scroll resize", function(){

      var winHeight = window.innerHeight, // altura da janela
          antOffset = $(".block_demarcacaolista")
                      .prev("div")
                      .offset().top, // distância da div anterior até o topo da janela
          antHeight = $(".block_demarcacaolista")
                      .prev("div")
                      .outerHeight(true), // altura da div anterior
          divHeight = winHeight-(antOffset+antHeight); // altura que a div poderá ter

      if(divHeight < 150) divHeight = 150; // define uma altura mínima de 150px

      $(".block_demarcacaolista").css({
         "height":
         (window.innerWidth > 767 ?
         divHeight-20+"px":
         "auto") // "20" é o espaço até o bottom da janela. Você pode ajustar se quiser
      });
   }).trigger("scroll");

});
```

**Veja em funcionamento:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $(window).on("scroll resize", function(){
      
      var winHeight = window.innerHeight, // altura da janela
          antOffset = $(".block_demarcacaolista")
                      .prev("div")
                      .offset().top, // distância da div anterior até o topo da janela
          antHeight = $(".block_demarcacaolista")
                      .prev("div")
                      .outerHeight(true), // altura da div anterior
          divHeight = winHeight-(antOffset+antHeight); // altura que a div poderá ter

      if(divHeight < 150) divHeight = 150; // define uma altura mínima de 150px

      $(".block_demarcacaolista").css({
         "height":
         (window.innerWidth > 767 ?
         divHeight-20+"px":
         "auto") // "20" é o espaço até o bottom da janela. Você pode ajustar se quiser
      });
   }).trigger("scroll");
   
});
```

```css
.block--footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
}

.block--navbar{
background-color: #030040;
}

.block__logo{
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
}

.block__input{
margin-top: 15px;
}

.block__btnprimary{
margin-top: 15px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 20px;
background: white;
color: blue;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: blue;
}

.block--navbar__logo{
width: 100px;
height: 35px;
}

.block--navbar__link {
font-size: 18px;
color: rgba($black, .5);
}

.block--navbar__icon {
font-size: 60px;
color: rgba($black, .5);
}

.block--navbar__link:hover {
font-size: 21px;
color: rgba($primaryDark, .8);
.block--navbar__icon{ color: rgba(blue, 0.8)};
}

.block--navbar__profile{
font-size: 23px;
color: rgba($black, .5);
}

.block__card{
width: 180px;
height: 100px;
text-align: end;
min-width: 50px;
font-size: 11px;
color: white;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border: 0ch;
}

.block__card:hover{
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
}

.block__card--pausa{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(138, 138, 4);
}

.block__card--agendado{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(228, 61, 32);
}

.block__card--aguardando{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: blue;
}

.block__card--feedback{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(11, 152, 207);
}

.block__card--homologacao{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(40, 5, 73);
}

.block__card--dados{
 font-size: 22px;
text-align: start;
}

.block_demarcacao{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #030040;
}

.block_demarcacaol{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #BF622D;
}

.block_demarcacao0{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: brown;
}

.block_demarcacaolista{
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: brown;
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid my-3 block_demarcacao0">

        <div class="row block_demarcacao">

            <div class="col-md-9 block_demarcacaol">
                <!--linha 1 dos cards -->
                <div class="row block_demarcacao">

                    <!--card 1-->
                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--aguardando">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Aguardando atendimento
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">5</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <!--card 2-->
                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--pausa">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Em Pausa
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">12</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <!--card 3-->
                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--feedback">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Aguardando Feedback
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-deaf"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">3</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>   
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--linha 2 dos cards-->
                <div class="row block_demarcacao">

                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--homologacao">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Em Homologação
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-bug"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">5</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--agendado">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Agendados
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">5</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!--FIM DOS CARDS -->

                <!--LISTA DE CHAMADOS -->
                <div class="row block_demarcacaolista">
                    <div class="container-fluid list-group" data-spy="scroll">

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 block_demarcacaol">
                <span>Aqui fica o SATI em atendimento</span>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: dvd, ainda não implementei no meu código, porém verificando aqui pelo site vi que é exatamente disso que eu estava falando, a div deve conter uma lista de chamados e por isso tem que ser scrollable, vou implementar, muito obrigado !

Comment: Blz... qualquer dúvida pode falar.

Answer (score 1):

Eduardo não entendi direito o que vc quer exatamente. Mas sobre o problema do Scroll vc consegue resolver sim colocando uma altura "fixa"

As observações que faço é que vc pode usar uma altura mínima ou máxima na `div` dessa forma que vai funcionar:

```
.block_demarcacaolista {
    max-height: 30vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

E vc também pode fazer Midias Querys para a altura dessa `div` também dessa forma por exemplo.

```
@media only screen and (min-height: 600px){
    .block_demarcacaolista {
        height: 200px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
```

Sobre o Scrollspy não entendi direto o que vc pretende, mas as ancoras estã funcionando, não mexi em nada no HTML só essas poucas linhas de CSS na `.block_demarcacaolista`

**Veja o exemplo funcionando.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- page 2-->
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <!-- metas obrigatórios para o bootstrap para compatibilidades-->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- LINK OBRIGATÓRIOS PARA BOOTSTRAP, SWEETALERT2 E ANIMATE.CSS-->
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Add icon library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <title>Home Page</title>

    <style>
    .block--footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
}

.block--navbar{
background-color: #030040;
}

.block__logo{
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
}

.block__input{
margin-top: 15px;
}

.block__btnprimary{
margin-top: 15px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 20px;
background: white;
color: blue;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: blue;
}

.block--navbar__logo{
width: 100px;
height: 35px;
}

.block--navbar__link {
font-size: 18px;
color: rgba($black, .5);
}

.block--navbar__icon {
font-size: 60px;
color: rgba($black, .5);
}

.block--navbar__link:hover {
font-size: 21px;
color: rgba($primaryDark, .8);
.block--navbar__icon{ color: rgba(blue, 0.8)};
}

.block--navbar__profile{
font-size: 23px;
color: rgba($black, .5);
}

.block__card{
width: 180px;
height: 100px;
text-align: end;
min-width: 50px;
font-size: 11px;
color: white;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border: 0ch;
}

.block__card:hover{
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
}

.block__card--pausa{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(138, 138, 4);
}

.block__card--agendado{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(228, 61, 32);
}

.block__card--aguardando{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: blue;
}

.block__card--feedback{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(11, 152, 207);
}

.block__card--homologacao{
@extend .block__card;
background-color: rgb(40, 5, 73);
}

.block__card--dados{
 font-size: 22px;
text-align: start;
}

.block_demarcacao{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #030040;
}

.block_demarcacaol{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #BF622D;
}

.block_demarcacao0{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: brown;
}

.block_demarcacaolista{
height: 350px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: brown;
}

.block_demarcacaolista {
    max-height: 50vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid my-3 block_demarcacao0">

        <div class="row block_demarcacao">

            <div class="col-md-9 block_demarcacaol">
                <!--linha 1 dos cards -->
                <div class="row block_demarcacao">

                    <!--card 1-->
                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--aguardando">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Aguardando atendimento
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">5</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <!--card 2-->
                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--pausa">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Em Pausa
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">12</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <!--card 3-->
                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--feedback">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Aguardando Feedback
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-deaf"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">3</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>   
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--linha 2 dos cards-->
                <div class="row block_demarcacao">

                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--homologacao">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Em Homologação
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-bug"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">5</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 my-2 ml-1">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body block__card--agendado">
                                <p class="card-title block__card--title">
                                    Agendados
                                </p>
                                <div class="row block__card--dados">
                                    <div class="col align-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col align-left">
                                        <p class="text-right">5</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!--FIM DOS CARDS -->

                <!--LISTA DE CHAMADOS -->
                <div class="row block_demarcacaolista">
                    <div class="container-fluid list-group" data-spy="scroll">

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row list-group-item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-goup-item">#36985</a>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Integração WIS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Eduardo</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>3:30</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%">3:30000000</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Retrabalho</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>Bruno Luzardi</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>WMS - Integração</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 ml-1">
                                    <span>06 dias</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 block_demarcacaol">
                <span>Aqui fica o SATI em atendimento</span>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!--Componentes opcionais mas importantissimos sempre seguindo essa ordem jquery, popper, bootstrap-->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scriptsSweet.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Obrigado @hugucsl, na verdade div onde fica <!--LISTA DE CHAMADOS--> deve ter uma posição fixa completando o bottom da tela até o footer, e ela pode conter vários chamados e queria q apenas essa DIV tivesse a barra de rolagem e não a pagina em si, a pagina deve ser fixa como uma tela de sistema mesmo, muito obrigado !!